# AngularJS ui-route not working

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

totally newbie on angularjs and ui-routes!
trying to get a basic ui-router to work with express, but no success until now.

trying to make two routes.

```
/admin
/admin/dashboard
```

created the following files:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" data-ng-app="testApp">
<head>
    <base href="/admin">
</head>
<body ng-controller="AdminCtrl">
    <div class="app" id="app" ui-view></div>

    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="../admin/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../admin/admin.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="../admin/dashboard.controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $stateProvider

            .state('admin', {
                url: '/admin',
                templateUrl: 'admin/admin.html',
                controller: 'AdminCtrl'
            })

            .state('admin.dashboard', {
                url: '/admin/dashboard/',
                templateUrl: 'admin/dashboard.html',
                controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

**admin.controller.js**

```
angular.module('testApp')
    .controller('AdminCtrl', function() {
        console.log("I'm AdminCtrl");
    });
```

**dashboard.controller.js**

```
angular.module('testApp')
    .controller('DashboardCtrl', function($scope) {
        console.log("I'm DashboardCtrl");
    });
```

**dashboard.html**

```
I'm the dashboard.html
```

**admin.html**

```
I'm the admin.html
```

Tried load the following urls on browser:

http://localhost:9000/admin/

http://localhost:9000/admin/dashboard

the two URLs have the same result:

- no error on console.
- all files loaded (no 404)
- the index.html show correctly
- on console, the "I'm AdminCtrl" shows (so, AdminCtrl loaded)
- the browser show only a blank page (the admin.html and dashboard.html don't have been loaded?)
- the message "I'm DashboardCtrl" never shown, then I think the DashboardCtrl was never called.

PS:
**routes.js (from express)**

```
app.route('/admin/*')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            res.sendfile(app.get('appPath') + '/admin/index.html');
        });
```

Comment: Some suggestions/pointers: 1) Don't use do `ng-controller="AdminCtrl"` in the HTML template when you are specifying the same controller in the route definition (when everything is working properly, this will cause 2 `AdminCtrl`'s to be instantiated). 2) In the route definition you define `admin.dashboard` as a child state of `admin`. So that means the HTML template for the admin state also needs a `<div ui-view>` in it. This is the placeholder for the child state's template.

Comment: 3) Are you sure your HTML templates are being loaded (where is the express route for templates? You should see evidence of the HTML templates being loaded or not in the browser console. 4) UI-Router catches exceptions and you won't see them on the console. Add an event handler for `$stateChangeError` to see why the route is not working.

Comment: Removed the ng-controller on index.html, placed a <div ui-view> on admin.html, and finally, I'm sure that the admin.html and dashboard.html has not loaded (looking in network tab on chrome tabs). Tried using the $stateChangeError to see any error, but I'm not sure if I made correctly, because no error shows in any place.

Comment: One way to add the $stateChangeError handler (add this to `app.js`):  `angular.module('testApp').run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
      console.log('stateChangeError', error);
    });`

Comment: tks! tried, but still no output on console (on chrome dev tools), and only a blank screen on browser!

Comment: It sounds like the route is not matching the URL (so it doesn't go to any state). For debugging (and for your app in general), you can specify a default state to go to when the URL does not match any states. Add this to your "run" block in `app.js`:  `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/admin');` If that works then at least you know what the problem is. Then try playing w/URL's, try: `<base href="/">` or playing w/the URL's in your states.

Comment: Almost got! with $urlRouterProvider, the link has been changed automatically, and everything is working now, but with strange url. Maybe some stupid configurations, but at least is working now! The final url become: http://localhost:9000/admin/#/admin and http://localhost:9000/admin/#/admin/dashboard

Comment: edited index.html (base href attribute), and app.js (routes), and everything is working correctly! tks Sunil D.

Answer (score 0):

Please mention your child controller in your html template , like as follows

```
 <div ng-controller="DashboardCtr">
```

and may be this link solve your issue https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views and https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your dashboard `url` has an ending slash on it. I'd try correcting that, and as Sunil D. said, you don't need to specify the Admin controller when you're defining them in your routes.

Secondarily, you could try renaming the state of dashboard to `dashboard` to prevent the parent/child relationship between admin and dashboard. Unless, that is, that's what you want. In which case, your admin.html page would have to have a `ui-view` as well.

Comment: The dashboard must be a child of admin. Tried putting a ui-view on admin.html, but no success

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure the 'admin/admin.html' and 'admin/dashboard.html' are accessable(just copy the url of yourhost.com/admin/admin.html on your borwser url box and check it).

and the reason "i'am DashboardCtrl" never shows is the url on `'admin.dashboard'` state shold be only `url: '/dashboard'`

Comment: Yes, both files are accessible by browser.

Comment: if you could share the files with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). it would be simpler to understand the problem.